# AttributeError: 'MyMainWindow' object has no attribute 'pushButton'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Trying to proceed click button event in my code but got some issue.

```
AttributeError: 'MyMainWindow' object has no attribute 'pushButton'
```

Seems, like **clicked** event can`t find **pushbutton** from my subclass. Probably i did some mistakes in syntax, so really waiting for your help guys. Sorry if the question very banal, pyQt5 is simply new for me, trying to figure out in all of this.

Here is my files.

***ui_main.py***

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.7.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(349, 131)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.label)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 349, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***py_main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, qApp
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QEvent, QObject
from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickButton()) #here is where the issue is occurs
        self.show()
        self.setupUi(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
                self.close()
        return super(MyMainWindow, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    def clickButton(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusbar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyMainWindow()
    test = TestClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Waiting forward for your help!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code there are 3 errors:

1. You must call the `setupUI` function first since the button is created here and then connect that button to the slot.
2. When the button is connected to the slot you just have to pass the slot name without parenthesis.
3. Change `statusbar()` to `statusBar()`.

Code:

```py
# ...
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        qApp.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickButton)
        self.show()
# ...
    def clickButton(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
# ...
```

Comment: what should if the form closes after pressing pushButton?

Comment: I do not understand you, explain yourself better.

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

**call the setupUI function first**

```
self.setupUi(self)          
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click_button)
```

tag `QDialog` and `Ui_Dialog`

**main.py**

```
MyMainWindow(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
```

**mainGui.py**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

OUTPUT:

SOLVED: AttributeError Main object has no attribute pushButton

[image]