# why does super(MainWindow, self),__init__(*args, **kwargs) NameError: name '__init__' is not defined

Tags: python, module, traceback, mainwindow

```
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import operator

from Calculator import Ui_MainWindow

# Calculator state.
READY = 0
INPUT = 1

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self),__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # setup numbers
        for n in range(0, 10):
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_nks' % n).pressed.connect(lambda v=n: self.input_number(v))

        # setup operation
        self.pushButton_add.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.add))
        self.pushButton_sub.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.sub))
        self.pushButton_mul.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.mul))
        self.pushButton_div.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.truediv))

        self.pushButton_pc.pressed.connect(self.operation_pc)
        self.pushButton_eq.pressed.connect(self.equals)

        # setup actions
        self.actionReset.triggered.connect(self.reset)
        self.pushButton_ac.pressed.connect(self.reset)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.pushButton_m.pressed.connect(self.memory_store)
        self.pushButton_mr.pressed.connect(self.memory_recall)

        self.memory = 0
        self.reset()

        self.show()

    def display(self):
        self.lodNumber.display(self.stack[-1])

    def reset(self):
        self.state = READY
        self.stack = [0]
        self.last_operation = None
        self.current_op = None
        self.display()

    def memory_store(self):
        self.memory = self.lodNumber.value()

    def memory_recall(self):
        self.state = INPUT
        self.stack[-1] = self.memory
        self.display()

    def input_number(self, v):
        if self.state == READY:
            self.state = INPUT
            self.stack[-1] = v
        else:
            self.stack[-1] = self.stack[-1] * 10 + v

        self.display()

    def operation(self, op):
        if self.current_op: #complete the current operation
            self.equals()

        self.stack.append(0)
        self.state = INPUT
        self.current_op = op

    def operation_pc(self):
        self.state = INPUT
        self.stack[-1] *= 0.01
        self.display()

    def equals(self):
        #support to allow '=' tp repeat previous operation
        #if no futher input has been added.
        if self.state == READY and self.last_operation:
            s, self.current_op = self.last_operation
            self.stack.append(s)

        if self.current_op:
            self.last_operation = self.stack[-1], self.current_op

            try:
                self.stack = [self.current_op(*self.stack)]
            except Exception:
                self.lodNumber.display('Err')
                self.stack = [0]
            else:
                self.current_op = None
                self.state = READY
                self.display()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setApplicationName("calculon")

    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

when I run this, I come across a problem that I can't solve on my own, I hope to find the answer here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:/Python35/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/qt ddesain/callKalkulator.py", line 109, in 
window = MainWindow()
File "C:/Python35/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/qt ddesain/callKalkulator.py", line 15, in **init**
super(MainWindow, self),**init**(*args, **kwargs)
NameError: name '**init**' is not defined

i got this kind of problem with my code like this, is there any way to solve it

Comment: That comma needs to be a period.

Answer (score 1):

It's a clear error in syntax for calling the constructor of parent class:

```
super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note than in python3, you can simply use `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: Well, it's not a _syntax_ error. Otherwise it would raise a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: I clearly believe I didn't user the exact wording _`SyntaxError`_ either. @Chris Modified the answer anyway.

Comment: You don't have to have said `SyntaxError`. If it's syntactically valid it isn't a syntax error. This is a _logic_ error, or a typo, however you want to look at it.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: What do you mean by example? Just replace `,` by `.` in your code as mentioned in the answer @Tegarrangga

Comment: where should I put it? honestly I just learned

Comment: Replace `super(MainWindow, self),__init__(*args, **kwargs)` by `super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` in your `__init__` method at line 15. @Tegarrangga

Comment: I have replaced it, and I found a new problem, can you help me?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\qt ddesain\callKalkulator.py", line 109, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\qt ddesain\callKalkulator.py", line 20, in __init__
    getattr(self, 'pushButton_nks' % n).pressed.connect(lambda v=n: self.input_number(v))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting @Jarvis

Comment: Replace `getattr(self, 'pushButton_nks' % n)` by `getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % n)` on line 20 @Tegarrangga

Comment: I've changed it, and I found a new problem again, can you help me again?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\qt ddesain\callKalkulator.py", line 109, in <module>
    window = MainWindow()
  File "C:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\qt ddesain\callKalkulator.py", line 20, in __init__
    getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % n).pressed.connect(lambda v=n: self.input_number(v))
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'pushButton_0'

Comment: I found the problem @jarvis

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272289/attributeerror-mymainwindow-object-has-no-attribute-pushbutton), also post your code as of now in a new question since the original issue has deviated from the current one and is resolved. Mark this answer as accepted to close this issue.

Comment: why can't I ask a question there